# Error when trying to verify contract

Tags: solidity, etherscan, verify

I'm trying to verify pn Etherscan my contract, but getting this error. What could it be?

```
PS C:\Projects\HardHat TS2> npx hardhat verify --network rinkeby 0x9517F72c4b61A07fd0cF684eE7A74C18Eb36dad8
Nothing to compile
No need to generate any newer typings.
An unexpected error occurred:

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Projects\HardHat TS2\artifacts\build-info\bd5e1b48863d1c1801c0a0353cc35891.json'] {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Projects\\HardHat TS2\\artifacts\\build-info\\bd5e1b48863d1c1801c0a0353cc35891.json'
}
```

contract to verify

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    constructor() ERC721("NFTforMarket", "NFT") {}

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    function mint(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        _tokenIds.increment();
        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the first thing you should check is whether or not the .json file is in the expected path.

`C:\Projects\HardHat TS2\artifacts\build-info\bd5e1b48863d1c1801c0a0353cc35891.json`

Comment: I checked the pass and there is no file with that name. (( so what should I do next?
How to use virual machine, is there any tutorials?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I got this error too and this worked:

1. Delete `artifacts` and `cache` folders
2. run `npx hardhat compile`
3. then verify

Answer (score 8):

You will need to delete the files and recompile:

1. run `npx hardhat clean`
2. run `npx hardhat compile`
3. try verify again.

`npx hardhat clean` deletes cache and artifacts :)

Answer (score 0):

I just again used `npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan`

Answer (score 0):

npx hardhat clean

fixed this problem for me.